# How to run the Apple Hardware Test in Snow Leopard on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, apple-hardware-test

I have a MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard.

I have an image of the Installation Disk in a USB Hard Drive (Snow Leopard Partition). Then to boot the system and start using the Hardware Test software I did this:

> 1. I change the Starup Disk to the 'Snow Leopard Partition'
> 2. I restart holding down the 'D' key

But it shows me a gray screen and the it start from the Snow Leopard Partition. But I can't see the Apple Hardware Test software.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Apple Hardware Test (AHT) was only able to run off of the Snow Leopard Application disc (disc two).  You will have to try the same procedure as you already have - holding D during startup - with the original disc in the drive.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, in Snow Leopard the Apple Hardware test was on the second install DVD, and would only run from the DVD (unless you manage to install it on the hard drive and run it from there).

See also the official Apple page: [Apple hardware test](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1509)

Comment: I lost the 2nd dvd. I'll try to get a new one from apple. Meanwhile, is there any other way to check the health of Mother board and Logic board?