# Reinstalation of Snow Leopard got stuck

Tags: snow-leopard

I would like to ask if you can help me with my problem.
My IMac got stuck so i tried to reinstall the operation system. However it got stuck and IMac is not responding at all only thing I can do is to turn it off.
Command +R is not working at all only by holding the Option button I can go to disk or CD none of these options are working Mac gots stuck
Can you plese advise what can I do to reinstall my IMac
I tried to reset NVRAM and SMC it didnt wor.When I am trying to install the os from CD via option button I get a white screen with apple logo and under it a loading circle starts to spin after fewminutes it gets stuck and nothing happens can you plese advise? Only noise is comming from the CD-rom but computer is not doing anything only option I have is to turn it off.I think my IMac is from 2009.

Comment: What do you mean by "got stuck"? Which specific iMac model do you have? If you reboot with the Option key and select the installation CD, what exactly does happen?

Comment: Hello well the Apple logo will appear on white screen and uder the logo a loading icon states to boot but after few minutes the booting stops and it gets stuck. I tried also to reset both SMC and NVRAM and the problem is still there. I think it is model 2009 (IMac)

Comment: Are you using the DVD that came with your Mac? If not, the can you edit your question and include any information on the DVD such as the version? Do you have access to any other Mac computers, which could be used to create a USB OS X flash drive installer? If so, what model/year Mac?

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac with Snow Leopard, there is no Recovery partition. The only way is using the install DVD or an USB key (but there is no base).

You can try the 2 procedure : Reset SMC, Reset NVRAN before retry your install.

Your DVD number 2 contains also AHT (hardware tests) : [How to run the Apple Hardware Test in Snow Leopard on a MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61738/how-to-run-the-apple-hardware-test-in-snow-leopard-on-a-macbook-pro)

Comment: hello thank you for reply . Can I please ask you how can I do those two options Reset SMC or NVRAN?

Comment: You find it on the apple site and it's depend of your Mac.

Comment: To reset NVRAM (aka PRAM): restart holding the Command, Option, P, and R keys. Tradition says to keep holding them until it's restarted & chimed three times, but it's actually reset by the second chime. See [Apple support document #HT204063](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063). To reset the SMC... it depends on the model, see [Apple support document #HT201295](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).